# making triangle with points - prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have 5 points coordinates and I want to write a program that show all triangles that can be made with these.
for example :

> - p1(2,1)
> - p2(4,2)
> - p3(4,1)
> - p4(5,1)
> - p5(6,3)

and the output should be something like this :

> - p1,p2,p3
> - p3,p4,p5
> - ...

Comment: Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: what did i wrong ?

Comment: @hessamsalehi *"what did i wrong ?"* You did not post any code and did not asking a quiestion.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried to write.

Answer (score 0):

So, naively, the only way three points do not create a triangle is if they are in a straight line. In your case, that would be when they share the same X or Y values. So let's grab three points and see if at least two of them are different from each other; if that's the case, it should be a triangle.

You complicate matters because your fact database is badly structured. In fact, I'm not going to use it at all, I'm going to make my own inspired by it:

```
point(p1, 2,1).
point(p2, 4,2).
point(p3, 4,1).
point(p4, 5,1).
point(p5, 6,3).
```

Now let's make the predicate:

```
triangle(P1, P2, P3) :-
  point(P1, X1, Y1), point(P2, X2, Y2), point(P3, X3, Y3),

  % first, make sure we have three different points
  dif(P1, P2), dif(P2, P3), dif(P1, P3),  

  % now, ensure that all three of the Ys and all three of the Xs are not equal
  \+ (X1 == X2, X2 == X3, X1 == X3),
  \+ (Y1 == Y2, Y2 == Y3, Y1 == Y3).
```

You should be able to use this predicate to output all of the valid points. In fact you will get some duplicates unless you add an ordering constraint. But this should get you on the right track.